# FormSubmit get data-attribute of form

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a form like the following:

```
<form id="form-12" data-length="120" data-height="240">
<!-- different input fields -->
</form>
```

I can track the formSubmit event but what i need to include into the event are the values inside the data-attributes. How is this possible with Google Tag Manager? Do i need to to this with Javascript or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Open GTM preview, submit the form, select the form submit event in the preview and inspect the state of your variables on the submit event. You can use any of them.

You won't have the data-attributes among them, however.

You will have to use JS to parse out all the attributes on formSubmit if the attributes are still there on it.

It's worse if they're not. Then you would have to make them available for the future submit on pageload, on button click or on a different suitable trigger.